# Flutter : if else on List class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items, and map into Text widget `ALL A`, and additional Text widget `ONLY B` for last one. Because items is dynamic from API, so I decided to hide `ONLY B` if total of items are more than 3, what the correct way for statement infront `..add`

**ORIGIN (Working)**

```
items.map((element) => Text("ALL A"))
.toList()
 ..add(
    Text("ONLY B"),
)
```

**Tried 1**

```
items.map((element) => Text("ALL A"))
.toList()
 if(items.length > 3) ..add(
    Text("ONLY B"),
)
```

**Tried 2**

```
items.map((element) => Text("ALL A"))
.toList()
 items.length > 3 ?? ..add(
    Text("ONLY B"),
)
```

Comment: check `Iterable.followedBy(...)`

Comment: @pskink `.toList().followedBy(Text("ONLY B")).toList()` ?

Comment: why do you need those `toList()`? cannot you use just `Iterable`s?